# Nesting Filter with Where Clause using If, Like, Or and AND in Excel Power Query

Tags: sql, excel, nested, powerquery

I work in manufacturing of devices with large number of traceable components, and i have a theoretical batch of data that looks like this:

[image: Theoretical Data]

I have in Excel some interchangeable Parameters like so:

```
SerialNumberP = GetParameter("SerialNumber"),
ProductCodeP = GetParameter("ProductCode"),
WorkOrderNumberP = GetParameter("WorkOrderNumber"),
PartCodeP = GetParameter("PartCode"),
BuildDateP = GetParameter("BuildDate"),
```

Using this I have been successful in doing a where clause to search for my data one by one by using the parameters like so

```
  Where
   a.SerialNumber in ("& SerialNumberP &")
```

However, since there are so many fields, some times the information available to us is different. Therefore in the different cells with the headings:

- Serial Numbers
- Product Code
- Work Order
- Part Code
- Part Batch

I would like to use `AND` and `OR` clauses in different cases where different information is available.

**For example:**

- If I want to have a specific serial number and a Part Batch or
- If I want to have the entire work order with the specific Part Batch
- If I want to see all of one product code that uses this Part Batch

What I have so far looks something along the lines of:

```
Where
          (a.SerialNumber in ("& SerialNumberP &")) 
    Or    (a.WorkOrderNumber in ("& WorkOrderNumberP &"))
    Or    (b.WorkOrderNumber in ("& WorkOrderNumberP &") _
                AND a.ComponentPartCode = '"& PartNumberP &"')
    Or    (a.ComponentPartCode = '"& PartNumberP &"' _
                AND a.SerialNumber in ("& SerialNumberP &"))
    Or    a.BatchNumber in ("& BatchNumberP &")
```

However as we all know it is an *inclusive `OR`* and using the field `Part Batch` alone will satisfy 2 different `OR` conditions, and will output both of them.

I would like to ask if there is a way to, with other fields in Excel Cells empty, be able to query with only limited information, say Serial Number and Part Number, and only output that one corresponding line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are setting up a dynamic SQL query string in Power Query by using parameters loaded from an Excel workbook? Because you are setting up the query string in M code, it is possible to conditionally create elements of the string. I have done similar things like this where I want have multiple fields I want to query, but may want to use any combination of fields to look at. My solutions was to use an AND inclusion for every field, and simply not create the line if no value was specified for that field. I think this is what you are trying to do, though I'm not 100% sure.

```
"SELECT * FROM yourtable " &

"WHERE a.SerialNumber <> NULL " & 

if SerialNumberP <> null then "AND a.SerialNumber IN ("& SerialNumberP &") " else "" &
if WorkOrderNumberP <> null then "AND a.WorkOrderNumber IN ("& WorkOrderNumberP &") " else "" &
if PartNumberP <> null then "AND a.ComponentPartCode IN ("& PartNumberP &") " else "" &
if BatchNumberP  <> null then "AND a.BatchNumber IN ("& BatchNumberP &") " else "" &

""
```

Comment: That looks interesting, did not know this was possible ie building parts of the string. I will try that and let you know. Thank you in advance! but just wondering how the where clause would look? as you've got quotation marks in front of your WHERE, and I am not sure how to build with that. could you please go from the From Clause? Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: I have no idea what your FROM would look like, but I put a dummy line in there if that helps. You can append together the string however you want, you just need to make sure you're leaving spaces between the appended elements (I just leave a space at the end of any substring).

Comment: Thanks, I understand it much better now because I've never nested conditions in between the SQL codes but I know now it can be done.